# Showing that this function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let, $f(x,y) = \frac{y^{2}-x^{2}y}{\lvert y-x^{2}\rvert}$ when $y \neq x^{2}$ and $0$ otherwise.

I was thinking about using the squeeze theorem and then taking the limit as $y \rightarrow x^{2}$ but I couldn't establish any meaningful inequalities. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : $y^2 - x^2y = y(y-x^2)$